# Anybody using codereview.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

This morning I saw a [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14781/account-hierarchy-code-review) asking for a code review so I thought about recommending the OP post at codereview.stackexchange until I noticed that they only have one Apex question, total. Should we direct these questions to Code Review? Anybody else up for watching for Apex questions over there?

Comment: Never knew such a SE site existed until today

Answer (score 7):

Given the fairly low volume of questions on this site, and the fact that most people here (myself included) don't follow codereview, I'd be totally up for simply accepting/allowing code review questions here. I don't see any problem with people posting well thought out questions for code review, and I don't think there's any more appropriate SE site than this one for Apex/VF code review.

Answer (score 4):

Sure - I just created a tag subscription on codereview for apex-code, visualforce, and a bunch of other likely tags.